# jQuery: How do I load a display a loading graphic before a large background image, set in css, loads then have the background image fade in?

Tags: jquery, image, background, load, fade

I am re-designing my personal website and have a full size image I am using as the background of the site. It takes a lot longer to load than the rest of the webpage and I cannot reduce the filesize anymore so...
Using jQuery, I wanted to display an animated loading gif in the background until the image loads then fade the image in.
I have the following jQuery code which fades the image in nicely;

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#bodybg').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

And I wanted thought about adding a class to the css id and then assign the loading image to the class and have jQuery strip the class out once the image loads. something like:

```
$('#bodybg') .removeClass('loading')
```

But I’m a little bit stuck on putting it altogether in a format that works? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a callback function to fadeIn.

```
$("#bodybg").fadeIn(2000, function(){
  $("#bodybg").removeClass('loading');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#bodybg').fadeIn();
});
```

Or you could load with a white screen and fade into the site:

css:

```
div#loading { position: absolute; top:0px ; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: white; z-index: 1000;}
```

and the Jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#loading').fadeOut();
});
```

and the html (right after the body tag)

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for that guys. Both of your inputs helped out. I managed to get the loader gif to display then fade out and the image to fade in once loaded. I now have a nice effect that indicates to the user that the page is loading and fades nicely.

HTML is...

```
<div class=loading style="display:none;"></div>
```

placed right after the body tag then...

```
<div class="bodybg"></div>
```

placed right after that.

The jQuery is...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#loading').fadeOut(8000);});
$(document).ready(function(){   
    jQuery('#bodybg').fadeIn(3000)});
```

I have the main content of the page fade in straight away at a speed of 3000 so this really all works well together.

The css for the setup is...

```
#bodybg { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(../images/body/mainbg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center 0 transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 0; }

#loading { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(../images/body/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat fixed center 100px; position: absolute; z-index:-1;}
```

When the webpage first loads into the browser the background is white with logo and content of the site visible straight away. Just above the main content the loader gif stays animated until the background image eventually loads and covers it while it fades out less than a second later behind the background.

Since the background image doesn't need to load after the users browser downloads it, navigating to other pages seems smooth as the loader gif shows up and fades out as the rest of the content fades in.

The help and guidance was much appreciated.

Andy Smiff